# Runge's Theorem for meromrophic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, approximation-theory

Is there a name for this extension of Runge's theorem?

**Theorem:** Let $K\subset\mathbb{C}$ be compact, and let $A\subset K^c$ be a set which intersects each component of $K^c$.  Let $f$ be meromorphic on an open set $U$ containing $K$.  Let $A_f$ denote the set of poles of $f$ in $K$.  Then there is a sequence of rational functions $\{r_n\}$ such that $r_n\to f$ uniformly on $K$, and for each $n$, the poles of $r_n$ are contained in the set $A\cup A_f$.

I have posted a proof of this result below.  It is such a natural generalization of Runge's theorem that I am sure it is known, but I would like a reference so that I can use it in a paper without proving it.

Thanks!

Comment: I have not seen this anywhere in the literature, but it certainly follows directly from Runge's approximation theorem. I would suggest simplifying your proof by subtracting the principal parts at each pole and then apply Runge's approximation theorem to the resulting analytic function. This is a little easier and more direct than your approach.

Comment: @LukasGeyer Thanks for the suggestion.  That is much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Proof:** Since $K$ is compact, we may impose the following assumptions on $K$:

1. $K$ consists of a finite union of closed balls.
2. The poles of $K$ are contained in the interior $K^\circ$.

Let $z_1,z_2,\ldots,z_k$ be the poles of $f$ in $K$ with multiplicities $m_1,m_2,\ldots,m_k$.  Define $q(z)=(z-z_1)^{m_1}\cdots(z-z_k)^{m_k}$, and define $g(z)=f(z)/q(z)$, which is analytic on some neighborhood of $K$.  As in user zhw.'s solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1289949/can-runges-approximating-rat-fns-be-required-to-take-certain-prescribed-value/1290604#1290604), we can find a sequence of rational functions $\{t_n\}$ such that $t_n\to g$ uniformly on $K$, and each $t_n$ has all of its poles in $A$, and for each $z_i$, each $t_n$ matches the value of $f$ and its first $m_k$ derivatives at $z_i$.  That is,

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
t_n(z_i)&=&g(z_i)\\
{t_n}'(z_i)&=&g'(z_i)\\
&\vdots\\
t_n^{(m_k)}(z_i)&=&g^{(m_k)}(z_i).
\end{array}$$

Define $r_n=t_n/q$.  Then each $r_n$ has all of its poles in $A\cup A_f$.

**CLAIM:** $r_n\to f$ uniformly on $K$.

Fix $\epsilon>0$, and define $M=m_1+m_2+\cdots+m_k$.  Choose a $\delta>0$ small enough so that at each pole $z_i$ of $f$ in $K$, the disk $B_{z_i}(3\delta)$ is contained in $K^\circ$, and contains no other poles of $f$ other than $z_i$.  Pick some $N>0$ such that for all $n>N$ and $z\in K$, $|t_n(z)-g(z)|<\epsilon\delta^M$.

Therefore if $z\in K$, with $|z-z_i|>\delta$ for all $i$, we have

$$|r_n(z)-f(z)|=\dfrac{|t_n(z)-g(z)|}{|q(z)|}<\dfrac{\epsilon\delta^M}{\delta^M}=\epsilon.$$

Now, for each $i\in\{1,\ldots,k\}$, the assumption on the function $t_n-g$ has a zero at $z_i$ of multiplicity $m_k$.  Therefore $r_n-f$ is analytic on is analytic at $z_i$, and therefore on all of $K$.  Now, for each $i\in\{1,\ldots,k\}$, $r_n-f$ is analytic on $B_{3\delta}(z_i)$, and has magnitude less than $\epsilon$on $\partial B_{\delta}(z_i)$, so by the maximum modulus theorem, $|r_n-f|<\epsilon$ on $B_{\delta}(z_i)$.

We have $|r_n-f|<\epsilon$ on $K$, so we conclude that $r_n\to f$ uniformly on $K$.